# How to get data from store?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex

How to get data from vuex store with vuejs?

Here is my code:
index.js

```
Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        data
    }
})
```

data.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const state = {
    data: ''
};

const getters = {
    getData: (state) => {
        return state.data;
    }
};

const actions = {
    async fetchData({ commit }, { id }) {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://someUrl?id=${id}`);
        console.log(response.data);
        commit('setData', response.data);
    }
}

const mutations = {
    setData: (state, data) => (state.data = data)
}

export default {
    state, getters, actions, mutations
}
```

Vue file where i want to fetch this data:

```
<script>
  import FooterComponent from "@/components/Footers/Footer.vue";

  import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        id: ""
      }
    },
    name: "Index",
    methods: {
      ...mapActions(["fetchData"]),
      launchFetchData() {
        this.fetchData({ id: this.id})
        this.$router.push("login");
      }
    },
    computed: mapGetters(["getData"])
  }
</script>
```

So, how to display data from vuex store on different vue file/template?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Where do you import your index.js ?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed out the spread operator and braces while defining mapGetter in computed property

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getData"])
}
```

After this you can access the getter using 'this' operator from any of your methods

for example:

```
methods: {
 sample() {
   console.log(this.getData);
 }
}
```

Comment: @svelteDev  - Great! If it works for you and you are happy - then in general you would accept the answer. This will not only help other people with the same issue but it will also mean people are more likely to help you in the future with any other issues you have. You can read about accepting here: stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer